# Gauss and $\int \frac{dn}{\log n}$

Tags: math-history

In [1], page 2, Edwards shows a tabulated table by Gauss, for $x$ (distinct and uniformly distributed values from $5\cdot 10^5$ to $3\cdot 10^6$), the count of primes$<x$, the symbol $\int \frac{dn}{\log n}$ and differences of previous computed quantities. In the following page the author discusses what might have understood Gauss by this amount $\int dn/\log n$. I know a standard topic in numerical analysis: Gauss quadratures. On page 2 is it also noted that Gauss knew the average of the density of prime numbers, and tabulations of primes that were published, thus I imagine that he computed using these informations the first column, this is the count of primes$<x$.

But I'm not sure what was the method for the second column, the symbol $\int \frac{dn}{\log n}$. For this reason I have the following question:

> **Question.** How were these quantities  $\int \frac{dn}{\log n}$ computed by Gauss? If you can give some detail, better.

References:

[1] Harold M. Edwards, Riemann's Zeta Function, Dover (edition) 2001.

Answer (score 1):

I believe he used the equivalent

$$
\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log x},
$$

and he had access to massive logarithm tables computed by hand by his peers.